What are different methods to track a moving object with stationary monocular camera
I am new to computer vision and trying to learn object tracking using vision. I read different books on vision where object tracking is discussed. Most of the books mention following two methods: 2d-Optical flow, structure from motion or stereo vision based tracking. I am trying to find out method/s to track moving object with fixed monocular camera. 2d-optical flow will not work as the object depth will not be available and I want to track object in 3d. Secondly, the assumption of constant light intensity in optical flow is frequently violated. stereo based vision or depth calculation based on triangulation will not work as the camera is stationary and is monocular.
Can anyone point me to the followings:

Classical method/s of 3d object tracking with fixed monocular camera.
Deep Learning based 3d object tracking with fixed monocular camera.( I know there are some papers on computing depth using a single image. But I want to understand the classical or underlying method of computing the depth and not just DL architecture.)


For an arbitrary object, especially an arbitrarily shaped one, I doubt that there's a way to get depth information from a 2D image.  For a simple example, how do you determine the range to a random balloon that is randomly inflating or deflating?

For simplicity, lets assume that the object being tracked is a regular shaped object i.e. a car of known shape. How do we track or detect this object with correct depth information using a fixed monocular camera? You can think about a traffic camera which is fixed and monocular.

If you have a calibrated camera, given the pixels in the image and the prior on the size of the object you could estimate the distance to the object.
Then you need to track it on the 2D image.
There few classic methods:

Template Based Methods
Correlation, Mean Shift, Kanade Lucas Tomasi Tracker.
Features Based Methods
Object Detection + Association, Optical Flow + Corners, Homography based.

For Deep Learning there are models which basically do a a template matching based on ViT (Visual Transformer). Using ViT makes the process robust and accurate.
The Deep Learning methods for single image depth estimation are mostly accurate in their "Relative" mode. Namely what's closer / farther and not the absolute value of the range.
